fantasy fighting movie - 80s or 90s
I'm looking for a weird movie in a fantasy or post-apocalyptic setting. It's an American (90% sure) or British movie. The main character is a Caucasian male with long blonde hair - he kinda looks like a singer in an 80s glam rock band.
This guy is on a sort of quest - fighting weird opponents which sometimes appear to be super-human. There are no weapons if I remember correctly, it's all fist fighting. It might be the fighting is part of a tournament of some sort, but the action is not stationary - the hero is moving around in a strange land.
I remember one scene - probably the final fight - where one fighter applies something like a five finger death punch, ripping out the opponents heart or at least trying to. I think the death punch scene was part of a fight with a black guy in tribal clothing...

This sounds very much like a movie called "The Silent Flute" released in 1978 (also known as Circle of Iron). 
The main character who looks Caucasian has long blonde hair and certainly would be at home in glam band The Sweet. 
He is on a quest in this movie for spiritual and martial art knowledge. He travels a strange land fighting and meeting strange people who each have something different or special about them. He gains knowledge either through defeating them or speaking with them.
Jeff Cooper plays the main guy known as Cord. David Carradine plays the other main character (many characters actually) in this movie which was originally written by Bruce Lee.




And that, Sir, is exactly the movie I was looking for. I squeaked like a piglet when watching the trailer. Let's break SE rules: Thank you very much.

Perhaps the 1995 live action version of "Fist of the Northstar"? It featured hand to hand combat in a post-apocalyptic world. The main character has long (though not blonde) hair.




You might want to elaborate in which way this movie fits to the dtails from the question in order to flesh out the answer a little more.
